# TypeError when calling Profile.object.create in django/python

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am getting the following error when I try to create a new profile.

```
Got a `TypeError` when calling `Profile.objects.create()`. This may be because you have a writable field on the serializer class that is not a valid argument to `Profile.objects.create()`. You may need to make the field read-only, or override the ProfileSerializer.create() method to handle this correctly.
Original exception was:
```

I am not sure why i am getting this error.

I have a model and serializer and views and urls. I am not even sure where the error is coming from in the process.

models.py

```
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(
        User, on_delete=models.CASCADE
    )
    synapse = models.CharField(max_length=25, null=True)
    bio = models.TextField(null=True)
    profile_pic = models.ImageField(upload_to='./profile_pics/',
                                    height_field=500,
                                    width_field=500,
                                    max_length=150)
    facebook = models.URLField(max_length=150)
    twitter = models.URLField(max_length=150)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username + self.synapse
```

profileViews.py

```
from users.models import Profile

from rest_framework.generics import ListAPIView, RetrieveAPIView, CreateAPIView
from rest_framework.generics import DestroyAPIView, UpdateAPIView

from users.api.serializers import ProfileSerializer


class ProfileListView(ListAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer


class ProfileRetrieveView(RetrieveAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer


class ProfileCreateView(CreateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer


class ProfileDestroyView(DestroyAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer


class ProfileUpdateView(UpdateAPIView):
    queryset = Profile.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProfileSerializer
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path

from users.api.views.profileViews import ProfileListView, ProfileRetrieveView, ProfileCreateView
from users.api.views.profileViews import ProfileDestroyView, ProfileUpdateView

urlpatterns = [
    path('', ProfileListView.as_view()),
    path('create/', ProfileCreateView.as_view()),
    path('update/<pk>/', ProfileUpdateView.as_view()),
    path('delete/<pk>/', ProfileDestroyView.as_view()),
    path('<pk>/', ProfileRetrieveView.as_view())
]
```

Serializer for Profile

```
class ProfileSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Profile
        fields = (
            'id',
            'user',
            'synapse',
            'bio',
            'profile_pic',
            'facebook',
            'twitter'
        )
```

does this mean i need to specify the image type. I want the profile pictures to be in the main users folder.

[image]

Comment: Where is your **`ProfileSerializer`** class? and what data are you using while doing POST requests?

Comment: You need to include the actual place where you create the profile object and with what data you use to do it. Like JPG already asked - it will be probably in your serializer.

Comment: I will add my serializer for profile.. @JPG

Comment: Can you add the input data also?

Comment: yeah... I can add a screenshot. i am adding it through django framework views @JPG